# How to \setmainfont when "randomfont.ttf" is in different folder?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, sharelatex

I'm currently working in sharelatex online Latex editor, using XeLaTeX. I had all the fonts working using the `fontspec` package, however once moved to the Fonts folder there is no way to make them work:

```
\setmainfont{./Fonts/Merriweather-Regular.ttf}%
  [Ligatures=TeX,
  BoldFont=./Fonts/Merriweather-Bold.ttf,
  ItalicFont=./Fonts/Merriweather-Italic.ttf,
  BoldItalicFont=./Fonts/Merriweather-BoldItalic.ttf]
```

Even replacing the `./Fonts/`, `/Fonts/`, `Fonts/`, etc.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't load the fonts with the relative path. Load them by their font names and specify the `ExternalLocation` key to point to your folder:

```
\documentclass{article}       

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=Fonts/]{AGaramondPro-Regular.otf}%
  [Ligatures=TeX,
  BoldFont=AGaramondPro-Bold.otf,
  ItalicFont=AGaramondPro-Italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf]

\begin{document}
This is some regular text.
\end{document}
```