# XeLaTeX, non-English characters don't display

Tags: xetex, texmaker

I use `XeLaTeX + View PDF` in `Texmaker` to create a pdf document. However, the Chinese characters don't display, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

PS: The configuration of `XeLaTeX` is `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.

Here is the test code.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\title{标题}
\author{作者}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{测试}
测试
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The default font is latin modern which does not cover Chinese, you need to specify a suitable font (any opentype font on your system)

Comment: I don't know about the Latin Modern fonts, which should be defaulted by XeLaTeX, but have you tried switching fonts with one that surely has all of your needed glyphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I view your question Firefox picked Microsoft YaHei font so I tell xetex to do the same:

[image]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Microsoft YaHei}
\title{标题}
\author{作者}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{测试}
测试
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx. It works. Where can I find a list of font names?

Comment: @SparkandShine depends a lot on which operating  system you are using. If you select an element on firefox and "inspect element" you can find out what font it is using, which is what I did above.  but most systems have some sort of font browser that lets you browse fonts on your system.

Comment: if you are on a mac they are in /Applications/Font Book.app

Comment: Check Windows available fonts by `Start --> Run --> %windir%\fonts --> OK`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374610/135961) with chars not shown properly ore not shown at all. 
First you have to be sure, if the font family you are using covers the chars you need. If it does, it isn't enough to chose this family, you have to copy the font files into an own folder and link them in as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230193/135961).