# Fancy Header with Greek is not getting displayed properly (Displayed with � characters)

Tags: xetex, fancyhdr

I have the following sample of text:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}



% Uncomment it and uncomment any \lipsum notation as well.
% Afterwards build and see how beautifull result is displayed

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Image settings
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Custom Environments
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Languages & fonts

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}

\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Page Configuration
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[L]{%
    % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername \thechapter. \fi
    % The chapter title
    \leftmark
}

\rfoot{ \thepage \hspace{1pt} / \pageref{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \rfoot{ \thepage \hspace{1pt} / \pageref{LastPage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------- Title and author

\title{kati ΙοΤ Τσακ Νορις LoRa.}
\date{Πανεπιστήμιο Πειραιώς - 2018}
\author{Κανένας Κανενόπουλος}

%---------------------------------------------------------------- Document meta & Link settings
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\sffamily}

%------------------------------------------------------------------ Color Settings
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%------------------------------------------------------------------ Table Settings
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%------------------------------------------------------------------ Source Code
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\newminted{cpp}{texcomments}
\newminted{python}{texcomments}
\newminted{json}{texcomments}
\newminted{bash}{texcomments}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Προτόκολλά που αξιοποιούνται σε μια επικοινωνία LoRa}
        \section{LoRa}
        \subsection{Προτόκολλα Layer 2 που αξιοποιούντε πάνω στο LoRa}
        Το πρωτόκολλο LoRa όπως προαναφέρθηκε είναι ένα πρωτόκολλο επιπέδου 1, αλλά πάνω σε αυτό υπάρχουν ποικίλα πρωτόκολλα επιπέδου 2, πράγμα που οφείλετε στο ότι το μόνο πατενταρισμένο και ιδιοταγές κομμάτι είναι η διαμόρφωση σήματος που είναι ενσωματωμένο στο τσιπ, τα ποιο διαδεδομένα είναι τα:



    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \def\arraystretch{1.0}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|L{6cm}|}

            \hline
            \rowcolor{red}
             \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Είδος Πακέτου}}} 
             &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Κωδικός*}}} 
             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Αποστολέας}}} 
             & \multicolumn{1}{C{6cm}|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Περιγραφή}}} \\
            \hline
            % ΕΙΔΟΣ ΠΑΚΕΤΟΥ & ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ & ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗ
            PUSH\_DATA & 0x00 & GATEWAY & Πακέτο στο οποίο προωθούνται τα δεδομένα από το node στον network server.\\
            PUSH\_ACK & 0x01 & NETWORK SERVER & Πακέτο επιβεβαίωσης ότι τα δεδομένα επιτυχώς απεστάλησαν.\\
            PULL\_DATA & 0x02 & GATEWAY & Πακέτο που αποστέλλετε ανά τακτά χρονικά διαστήματα για την λήψη δεδομένων για τα nodes. \\
            PULL\_ACK & 0x04 & NETWORK SERVER & Πακέτο επιβεβαίωσης ότι υπάρχουν δεδομένα που μπορεί να λάβει το gateway.\\
            PULL\_RESP & 0x03 & NETWORK SERVER & Πακέτο που εμπεριέχει τα δεδομένα που θα αποσταλούν από τα nodes.\\
            TX\_ACK & 0x04 & GATEWAY & Πακέτο που επιβεβαιώνει ότι λήφθηκαν τα παραπάνω δεδομένα\\
            \hline

            \rowcolor{gray}\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\small{\textbf{* Δεκαεξαδική τιμή στο τρίτο πεδίο του header }}}}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Τα είδη των πακέτων που ανταλλάσσονται στο Semtech UDP προτόκολλο}
        \label{SEMTECHUDP:PACKETTYPES}
    \end{table}

    \subsection{Headers και δομή json}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
            \centering
            \def\arraystretch{1.0}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|L{6cm}|}
                \hline
                \rowcolor{red}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Θέση Byte}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Λειτουργία}}} \\ \hline
                % ΘΕΣΗ BYTE & ΛΕΙΤΟΥΡΓΙΑ
                0 & Έκδοση Πρωτοκόλλου \\
                1-2 & Τυχαίος Αριθμός \\
                3 & Ιdentifier μηνύματος όπως αναφέρετε στον πίνακα \ref{SEMTECHUDP:PACKETTYPES}.\\
                4-11 & Identifier του gateway (συνήθως η MAC address της κάρτας δικτύου)\\
                \hline
                \rowcolor{gray}\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\small{\textbf{\textcolor{white} {ΜΕΓΕΘΟΣ ΚΕΦΑΛΙΔΑΣ:} \textcolor{red}{12bytes}}}}\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Κεφαλίδα η οποία χρησιμοποιείτε όταν ο αποστολέας ενός πακέτου είναι το gateway.}
            \label{SEMTECHUDP:HEADER:GATEWAY}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \def\arraystretch{1.0}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|L{6cm}|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{red}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Θέση Byte}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Λειτουργία}}} \\ \hline
            % ΘΕΣΗ BYTE & ΛΕΙΤΟΥΡΓΙΑ
            0 & Έκδοση Πρωτοκόλλου \\
            1-2 & Αριθμός στον οποίο έχει στείλει το gateway και περιμένει την απάντηση \\
            3 & Ιdentifier μηνύματος όπως αναφέρετε στον πίνακα \ref{SEMTECHUDP:PACKETTYPES}.  \\
            \hline
            \rowcolor{gray}\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\small{\textbf{\textcolor{white} {ΜΕΓΕΘΟΣ ΚΕΦΑΛΙΔΑΣ:} \textcolor{red}{4bytes}}}}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Κεφαλίδα η οποία χρησιμοποιείτε όταν ο αποστολέας ενός πακέτου είναι το gateway.}
        \label{SEMTECHUDP:HEADER:NSERVER}
    \end{table}

    Υπάρχουν 2 ειδών κεφαλίΧΨΝΑΙΣΨΗΒΘΣΔΑΨΒΣΘΔΑΦΨΒΣΘΟΔΑΨΒΣΟΙΔΨΒΗΣΛΔΑΨ αποστολέας του μηνύματος είναι το Gateway και περιγράφετε από τον πίνακα \ref{SEMTECHUDP:HEADER:GATEWAY} και το άλλο όταν ο αποστολέας είναι ο network server \ref{SEMTECHUDP:HEADER:NSERVER}. Όπως παρατηρείτε το gateway αποστέλλει μεγαλύτερη σε μέγεθος κεφαλίδα σε σύγκρισή με την κεφαλίδα της απάντησης του network server. Αξιοσημείωτο δε είναι ότι ο network server στο δεύτερο και τρίτο byte δεν αποστέλλει τυχαίες ποσότητες αλλά αξιοποιεί την ποσότητα την οποία έχει στείλει το gateway και ουσιαστικά ο network server λέει για ποιο μήνυμα απαντά. Τα δεδομένα που βρίσκονται μετά την κεφαλίδα είναι σε μορφή JSON.

    Ακόμη η μορφή και η δομή του Json payload του μηνύματος διαφέρει ανάλογα με το εάν ο αποστολέας είναι το gateway ή ο network server. Στην πρώτη περίπτωση το json payload έχει 2 sections όπως βλέπετε παρακάτω:
    \begin{jsoncode}
{
   "rxpk":[ {...}, ...],
   "stat":{...}
}
    \end{jsoncode}
    To \texttt{rxpk} κομμάτι εμπεριέχει πληροφορίες σχετικά με τα πακέτα που, έλαβε το gateway ενώ το \texttt{stat} εμπεριέχει πληροφορίες για το gateway αυτό καθέ αυτό. Σε ένα πακέτο που αποστέλει το gateway πρέπει τουλάχιστον στο payload του να εμπεριέχει ένα από τα 2.

    Στην δεύτερη περίπτωση το payload διαφέρει ανάλογα από τον τύπο του μυνήματος, συνήθως εμπεριέχει ένα JSON object, εάν το μήνυμα είναι τύπου \textit{PULL\_RESP} τότε το JSON payload εμπεριέχει τα δεδομένα που θα αποστείλει το gateway και έχει την εξής μορφή:
    \begin{jsoncode}
{
   "txpk":[ {...}, ...]
}
    \end{jsoncode}
    Ενώ εάν είναι τύπου \textit{TX\_ACK} τότε ΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΣΑΔΑ την κατάσταση των ληφθέντων μηνυμάτων και είναι της εξής μορφής:
    \begin{jsoncode}
{
    "txpk_ack":{...}
}
    \end{jsoncode}

    Τα chip τα οποία επιτρέπουν επικοινωνία με το LoRa είναι τα ακόλουθα:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{HopeRF RFM9x Series}  RFM9XCHIPSET
        \item \textbf{Semtech SX127x} SX127XCHIPSET
        \item \textbf{Microchip RN2483 and RN2903} RNMICROCHIPLORA
    \end{enumerate} 
    Tα chip από την HopeRF RFM9x  και την Semtech SX127x  χρησιμοποιούν την σειριακή διεπαφή the SPI  για την επικοινωνία με τον μικοελεγχτή ή τον μικροεπεξεργαστή, εν αντιθέσει τα chip της Microchip χρησιμοποιούν την UART διεπαφή . Στην περίπτωσή μας χρησιμοποιήσαμε   δασσαδσαφσδαφασδφδσαφασζδασσαΔ2    οποίο αξιοποιεί τα chip της Semtech.

    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \def\arraystretch{1.0}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|L{5cm}|L{5cm}|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{red}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Όνομα}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Λειτουργία}}} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Εικόνα}}} \\ \hline
            % Όνομα & ΛΕΙΤΟΥΡΓΙΑ
            3.3V & Τροφοδοσία τάσης 3.3 Volt & \multirow{13}{*}{ΠΟΛΥ ΜΕΦΑΛΟ ΚΕΙΜΕΝΟ} \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            GND & Γείωση (2 pin) & \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            MISO & Έξοδος δεδομένων SPI & \\ 
            \hhline{--|~}
            MOSI & Είδοδος δεδομένων SPI & \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            SCK  & Ρολόι SPI & \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            NSS  &  Είσοδος δασδσαδασ Chip Select & \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            RESET &  Λειτουργία δασδσαδσαδα Chip & \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            ANT & Κεραία & \\
            \hhline{--|~}
            DIO0 & \multirow{6}{*}{\parbox{5cm}{δσαδσα - ασδσαδασ γενικού σκοπού. \newline Αξιοποιούνται για διάφορες λειτουργίες πάνω στο τσιπ.}} \\
            DIO1 & \\
            DIO2 & \\
            DIO3 & \\
            DIO4 & \\
            DIO5 & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Διάταξη και περιγραφή pin. Η διεπαφή SPI είναι στο κόκκινο περίγραμμα στην εικόνα.}
        \label{CHIP:PINOUT}
    \end{table}

    Η διάταξη του pin και για την σειρά HopeRF RFM9x και την σειρά Semtech SX127x αποτελούνται είναι αυτό που δείχνει ο πίνακας \ref
    Για χρήστη στα 433ΜHz ενδείκνυνται η χρήση του fork \url{https://github.com/the-louie/arduino-lmic}  και το ρυθμίζετε από το αρχείο που αναφέρθηκε προηγουμένως. Εναλλακτικά μπορείτε να αλλάξετε τις ακόλουθες γραμμές στο αρχείο \texttt{/src/lmic/config.h} αντικαθιστώντας τις γραμμές:

    \begin{cppcode}
enum { EU868_F1 = 868100000,      // g1   SF7-12
    EU868_F2 = 868300000,      // g1   SF7-12 FSK SF7/250
    EU868_F3 = 868500000,      // g1   SF7-12
    EU868_F4 = 868850000,      // g2   SF7-12
    EU868_F5 = 869050000,      // g2   SF7-12
    EU868_F6 = 869525000,      // g3   SF7-12
    EU868_J4 = 864100000,      // g2   SF7-12  used during join
    EU868_J5 = 864300000,      // g2   SF7-12   ditto
    EU868_J6 = 864500000,      // g2   SF7-12   ditto
};
    \end{cppcode}
\end{document}
```

But some headers are getting displayed like:

[image]

Do you know how I can fix that?
I believe that is related somehow with wither on how I compile it:

```
xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

Or that I extensively use tables and images on the text.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot reduce the preamble of your document to illustrate the problem?

Comment: No I cannot reduce it because the problem itself is hard to reproduce and cannot find out how it happened.

Comment: (1) you do not need images to show the problem, I guess (2) surely you do not need `minted`: people without python installed will not be able to test it (3) compiling with `xelatex -shell-escape` I get a correct output. Maybe this is the problem of a pdf viewer?

Comment: (1) I reduced the preample (2) With minted the prob is not getting reproduced (3) But either my editor's and the evince shows the very same output and is the wrong one. Even if something missing I need to put it in order to work correctly

Comment: does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274193/xelatex-non-english-characters-dont-display?rq=1 help?

Comment: For me the code in the question works without problems. Given your own solution, maybe there is something wrong with your installed fonts (availability of serif/sans-serif characters)? Do you get any warnings or errors in the terminal or in the log file? You could try switching off `nonstopmode` for debugging.

Comment: Yes actually is a font issue, especially after a page full of tables.

Comment: you shouldn't use xltxtra and xunicode. Beside this one can see that the ttfamily font is used in the header and this has not greek. This can e.g happen if there is page break in the middle of minted code. Add \normalfont to the header definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason in your text the header's fonts are being messed up you can enforce into serif font via changing the:

```
\fancyhead[L]{%
    % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername \thechapter. \fi
    % The chapter title
    \leftmark
}
```

Part of your text into:

```
\fancyhead[L]{%
    % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \textsf{\chaptername \thechapter}. \fi
    % The chapter title
    \textsf{\leftmark}
}
```

If you look carefully I mark the printable parts with `\textsf` meaning that this part will get displayed using serif font. Therefore if XeLaTeX misrenders the headers due to overuse of tables and figures by enforcing the serif use of fonts is getting displayed like a charm.