# XeTeX shows special characters as squares, even though they are covered by the family

Tags: fonts, xetex, characters

Still looking for a way to get all those special chars covered that I need in my project. So I tryed to use XeTeX as it seems to work best with Unicode.
And it does. Nearly.
At least it shows chars that other compilation systems don't show. But some of them are shown as square, as if the font family wouldn't contain them, but it definitely does!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
123456789↊↋0 °á ô
\end{document}
```

The font type of my editor is Times New Roman and all chars are shown while coding. But when I render the preview it only shows squares instead of ↊ and ↋. Why?

Comment: XeTeX perhaps find some other font. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to get more info in the log-file. Btw: xltxtra is more or less obsolete, use simply fontspec. And the Mapping is not needed if your system is not too old.

Comment: Okay thanks! I deleted the obsolete stuff and it still works.
But the main problem isn't solved. Can't quite find out what it is doing but changing the font definitely works correctly so I guess it should be Times New Roman when I tell it to be.
Is there a command list für XeTeX anywhere? Per haps I can help myself. Didn't find any by googleing.

Comment: What happens if you use lualatex instead of xelatex?

Comment: On my machine (Mac OS X) the Times New Roman font doesn't cover those characters. I have several fonts on my system (free or included in the OS) and only Symbola covers them. What makes you think they're covered?

Comment: @ UlrikeFischer The chars are not shown, not even as squary thingys.

@ egreg Times New Roman shows the chars in LibreOffice Writer and in the coding window of texmaker, just not in the resulting pdf. But thanks, I will try Symbola (if I have it on windows)

Comment: Then your font doesn't have the chars. (On my system, windows, I get them). That you see them in other applications is not a proof: they often use fallback fonts for missing chars.

Comment: It definitely has them, I checked the char table. They are both in it, as well as in the font family Tahoma. But Tahoma also doesn't work. Is it a bug?

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80lUV.png) using cygwin texlive 2017 xetex, and times roman from windows 10, it is impossible to say from the information you have posted whether your problem is an old font or an old copy of xetex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer! :D
It is [Here!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230193/135961)
I did as Werner said, but with Times New Roman and now all chars are shown properly! 
Thanks to all who tried to help! Case is closed. ;)